# Appium get xpath from element?

Tags: ios, ruby, xpath, appium

I have code which retrieves a static text element for me fine but what I want to do is then get the xpath of that element as a string. I'm using ruby. At this point I have an array of elements I have already retrieved. Below is what I've tried but no luck.

```
elements.each do |element|

  if element.attribute("name").include? vProblem
    p "Problem found, retrieving xpath..."

    # Neither of these work
    p "Problem xpath is: " + element.attribute("xpath").to_s
    p "Problem xpath is: " + element.xpath.to_s

  end
end
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a way as there are infinite possible xpaths. Also you already know an xpath from the information in the if statement e.g. `//*[@name='vProblem']` (within elements)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's an easy method or setting to call which will give you the xpath value.  You would have to determine it yourself.  To do this, iterate through all elements on the page until you found one that (A) matched the class of the element you're looking for and (B) matches the name/value of the element.

The only issue with this approach is that it assumes that the first element matching the class and value is the correct element.  If there are multiple elements with the same class and value, it will only find the first.